# Expression for the energy in the limit case of weak gravitational field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, metric-tensor

I'm trying to solve the following problem of General Relativity.

> Consider a particle of mass $m$ which moves following a geodesic in a space-time with metric $$ ds^2 = - e^{2U_n(\textbf{x})/c^2}c^2 dt^2 + h_{ij}(\textbf{x})dx^i dx^j$$
>
> where $U_n(\textbf{x})$ is the Newton gravitational potential. Prove that in the non-relativistic limit of weak field the following equation holds: $$E=mc^2(1+\frac{U_n}{c^2} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{v^2}{c^2})$$

What I've done so far is the following.

If we consider an inertial system of reference where the observer is at rest in the origin the energy is just:

$$E =  P^0 = m u^0$$

Where $u^{\mu}$ is the 4-velocity of the particle. So I just have to calculate the time component of the 4-velocity.

To do that I apply that the 4-velocity is a unit timelike vector, so:

$$g_{ab}u^au^b = -1$$

And this is equal to:

$$- e^{2U_n(\textbf{x})/c^2}c^2 (u^0)^2 + H = -1 $$

Where $H$ are the rest of the terms. Expanding the exponential up to order 2 using Taylor we get:

$$u^0 c \left( 1 + \frac{U_n}{c^2} + \frac{v^2}{c^4} \right) = 1 + H$$

Here I got stuck and I feel that something is not working. I should have the parenthesis in the RHS. This would happen if my metric would be $ds^2=-e^{-2U_n(\textbf{x})/c^2}c^2 dt^2 + \dots$ instead of the one that I have right now. Also the factor $c^2$ that appears in the equation is missing.

**Is my reasoning right and there is a problem with the calculations or is my reasoning incorrect? Is the statement of the problem correct?**

Comment: I might be wrong, but when you have $c\ne 1$, shouldn't the unit timelike vector condition be $u_au^a=-c^2$? By dimensional analysis one sees that $u_au^a=-1$ can't be correct (if $c$ is dimensionful).

Comment: @Adolfo : where is this question from? Only there's such a thing as the [mass deficit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy#Mass-energy_relation). When you drop a particle, potential energy is converted into kinetic energy, and when this is dissipated, you're left with a mass deficit. See [Mass in General Relativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity#Questions.2C_answers.2C_and_simple_examples_of_mass_in_general_relativity) on Wikipedia.